# codeigniter - Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using xampp 1.77 version, codeigniter 1.7.2 with flexigrid.
I follow step by step this tutorial https://gembelzillonmendonk.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/flexigrid-and-codeigniter-with-advanced-searching-with-example/#comment-353 but I don't understand which code must have **flexigrid.php** in `CI_Folder\system\application\controllers\flexigrid.php.`

My **flexigrid.php** code is this:

```
<?php
class Flexigrid extends Controller {

    function Flexigrid  ()
    {
        parent::Controller();   
        $this->load->helper('flexigrid');
    }

    function index()
    {
        //ver lib

        $this->load->model('ajax_model');
        $records = $this->ajax_model->get_select_countries();

        $options = '';
        foreach( $records as $v ) {
            $options .= $v['name'] . ';';
        }
        $options = substr($options, 0, -1);

        /*
         * 0 - display name
         * 1 - width
         * 2 - sortable
         * 3 - align
         * 4 - searchable (2 -> yes and default, 1 -> yes, 0 -> no.)
         */
        $colModel['id'] = array('ID',40,TRUE,'center',2);
        $colModel['iso'] = array('ISO',40,TRUE,'center',0);
        $colModel['name'] = array('Name',180,TRUE,'left',1);
        $colModel['printable_name'] = array('Printable Name',120,TRUE,'left',1,'options' => array('type' => 'date'));
        $colModel['iso3'] = array('ISO3',130, TRUE,'left',1, 'options' => array('type' => 'select', 'edit_options' => $options));
        $colModel['numcode'] = array('Number Code',80, TRUE, 'right',1, 'options' => array('type' => 'select', 'edit_options' => ":All;AND:AND;KK:KK;RE:RE"));
        $colModel['actions'] = array('Actions',80, FALSE, 'right',0);


        /*
         * Aditional Parameters
         */
        $gridParams = array(
        'width' => 'auto',
        'height' => 400,
        'rp' => 15,
        'rpOptions' => '[10,15,20,25,40]',
        'pagestat' => 'Displaying: {from} to {to} of {total} items.',
        'blockOpacity' => 0.5,
        'title' => 'Hello',
        'showTableToggleBtn' => true
        );

        /*
         * 0 - display name
         * 1 - bclass
         * 2 - onpress
         */
        $buttons[] = array('Delete','delete','test');
        $buttons[] = array('separator');
        $buttons[] = array('Select All','add','test');
        $buttons[] = array('DeSelect All','delete','test');
        $buttons[] = array('separator');


        //Build js
        //View helpers/flexigrid_helper.php for more information about the params on this function
        $grid_js = build_grid_js('flex1',site_url("/ajax"),$colModel,'id','asc',$gridParams,$buttons);

        $data['js_grid'] = $grid_js;
        $data['version'] = "0.36";
        $data['download_file'] = "Flexigrid_CI_v0.36.rar";

        $this->load->view('flexigrid',$data);
    }

    function example () 
    {
        $data['version'] = "0.36";
        $data['download_file'] = "Flexigrid_CI_v0.36.rar";

        $this->load->view('example',$data); 
    }
}
?>
```

When i type `http://127.0.0.1/flexiadvanced/index.php/flexigrid` browser give me a error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\flexiadvanced\system\application\models\ajax_model.php on line 34
```

this is the code of `ajax_model.php`

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Eye View Design CMS module Ajax Model
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * @category  CodeIgniter
 * @package   EVD CMS
 * @author    Frederico Carvalho
 * @copyright 2008 Mentes 100Limites
 * @version   0.1
*/

class Ajax_model extends Model 
{
    /**
    * Instanciar o CI
    */
    public function Ajax_model()
    {
        parent::Model();
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function get_select_countries()
    {
        //Select table name
        $table_name = "country";

        //Build contents query
        $separator = (string) ',';
        //$this->db->select('concat(iso3, concat('. addcslashes($separator) .', iso3))')->from($table_name);

        $query = $this->db->query("select concat(iso3, concat(':', iso3)) as name from country where iso3 is not null");
        //Get contents
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_countries() 
    {
        //Select table name
        $table_name = "country";

        //Build contents query
        $this->db->select('id,iso,name,printable_name,iso3,numcode')->from($table_name);
        $this->CI->flexigrid->build_query();

        //Get contents
        $return['records'] = $this->db->get();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        //Build count query
        $this->db->select('count(id) as record_count')->from($table_name);
        $this->CI->flexigrid->build_query(FALSE);
        $record_count = $this->db->get();
        $row = $record_count->row();

        //Get Record Count
        $return['record_count'] = $row->record_count;

        //Return all
        return $return;
    }

    /**
    * Remove country
    * @param int country id
    * @return boolean
    */
    public function delete_country($country_id) 
    {
        $delete_country = $this->db->query('DELETE FROM country WHERE id='.$country_id);

        return TRUE;
    }
}
?>
```

My database is called `country` and database table is called also `country`. This is information in `CI_Folder\system\application\config`

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "";
$db['default']['database'] = "country";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
```

Can you help me to write correct code inside flexigrid.php?
 
 
This is my code for **CI_Folder\system\application\helpers\flexigrid_helper.php** but is correct?

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Flexigrid CodeIgniter implementation
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * @category  CodeIgniter
 * @package   Flexigrid CI
 * @author    Frederico Carvalho (frederico@eyeviewdesign.com)
 * @version   0.3
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Frederico Carvalho  (http://flexigrid.eyeviewdesign.com)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt)
 * and GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
*/
if (! function_exists('build_grid_js'))
{
        /**
         * Build Javascript to display grid
         *
         * @param       grid id, or the div id
         * @param       url to make the ajax call
         * @param       array with colModel info:                
         *                      * 0 - display name
         *                      * 1 - width
         *                      * 2 - sortable
         *                      * 3 - align
         *                      * 4 - searchable (2 -> yes and default, 1 -> yes, 0 -> no.)
         *                      * 5 - hidden (TRUE or FALSE, default is FALSE. This index is optional.)
         * @param       array with button info:        
         *                      * 0 - display name
         *                      * 1 - bclass
         *                      * 2 - onpress
         * @param       default sort column name
         * @param       default sort order
         * @param       array with aditional parameters
         * @return      string
         */
        function build_grid_js($grid_id,$url,$colModel,$sortname,$sortorder,$gridParams = NULL,$buttons = NULL)
        {
                //Basic propreties
                $grid_js = '<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){';
                $grid_js .= '$("#'.$grid_id.'").flexigrid({';
                $grid_js .= "url: '".$url."',";
                $grid_js .= "dataType: 'json',";
                $grid_js .= "sortname: '".$sortname."',";
                $grid_js .= "sortorder: '".$sortorder."',";
                $grid_js .= "usepager: true,";
                $grid_js .= "useRp: true,";

                //Other propreties
                if (is_array($gridParams))
                {
                        //String exceptions that dont have ' '. Must be lower case.
                        $string_exceptions = array("rpoptions");

                        //Print propreties
                        foreach ($gridParams as $index => $value) {
                                //Check and print with or without ' '
                                if (is_numeric($value)) {
                                        $grid_js .= $index.": ".$value.",";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        if (is_bool($value))
                                                if ($value == true)
                                                        $grid_js .= $index.": true,";
                                                else
                                                        $grid_js .= $index.": false,";
                                        else
                                                if (in_array(strtolower($index),$string_exceptions))
                                                        $grid_js .= $index.": ".$value.",";
                                                else
                                                        $grid_js .= $index.": '".$value."',";
                                }
                        }
                }

                $grid_js .= "colModel : [";

                //Get colModel
                foreach ($colModel as $index => $value) {
                        $grid_js .= "{display: '".$value[0]."', ".($value[2] ? "name : '".$index."', sortable: true," : "")." width : ".$value[1].", align: '".$value[3]."'".(isset($value[5]) && $value[5] ? ", hide : true" : "")."},";  

                        //If item is searchable
                        if ($value[4] != 0)
                        {
                                //Start searchitems var
                                if (!isset($searchitems))
                                        $searchitems = "searchitems : [";

                                $options = '';                         
                                if (isset($value['options'])) {
                                        if (isset($value['options']['type'])) {
                                                $options = ", type : '".$value['options']['type']."'";
                                                switch($value['options']['type']) {
                                                        case 'select'   : $options .= ", editoptions : { value : '" . $value['options']['edit_options'] . "' }"; break;
                                                        case 'date'             :
                                                        case 'radio'    :
                                                        case 'checkbox' :
                                                        default                 :
                                                }
                                        }
                                }

                                if ($value[4] == 2)
                                        $searchitems .= "{display: '".$value[0]."', name : '".$index."', isdefault: true " .$options. "},";
                                else if ($value[4] == 1)
                                        $searchitems .= "{display: '".$value[0]."', name : '".$index."' " .$options. "},";
                        }

                }
                //Remove the last ","
                $grid_js = substr($grid_js,0,-1).'],';
                $searchitems = substr($searchitems,0,-1).']';

                //Add searchitems to grid
                $grid_js .= $searchitems;

                //Get buttons
                if (is_array($buttons))
                {
                        $grid_js .= ",buttons : [";
                        foreach ($buttons as $index => $value) {
                                if ($value[0] == 'separator')
                                        $grid_js .= "{separator: true},";
                                else
                                        $grid_js .= "{name: '".$value[0]."', bclass : '".$value[1]."', onpress : ".$value[2]."},";
                        }
                        //Remove the last ","
                        $grid_js = substr($grid_js,0,-1).']';
                }

                //Finalize
                $grid_js .= "}); })</script>";

                return $grid_js;
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: check in your application/config/autoload.php that you have this line `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); ` where database i have added to automatically load

Comment: Line 42 of autoload.php I have only this code `$autoload['libraries'] = array();` I try to edit into $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); but when I reload on browser using http://127.0.0.1/flexiadvanced/index.php/flexigrid it give me output **Fatal error: Call to undefined function site_url() in C:\xampp\htdocs\flexiadvanced\system\application\controllers\flexigrid.php on line 67** This is the complete code of autoload.php: http://pastebin.com/yLxkB1mW

Comment: This is my code for CI_Folder\system\application\helpers\flexigrid_helper.php** but is correct? http://pastebin.com/65xjF0va

Comment: instead of site_url try using `base_url()` which you havet o again define in your config.php file. `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Answer (score 0):

I solve looking here: https://github.com/sameersemna/ci-flexigrid

Just download codeigniter-flexigrid project, import database and set database credentials in database.php.

This is the live example from github project:

http://ci-flexigrid.sameershemna.com/countries

I like this solution because you do not need grocery-crud library but just simply codeigniter

cheers